# Scanner reading from file instead of console

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to evaluate postfix expression by fetching the expressions from a file using command "java PostFix < in.dat". Now when I want to fetch the value of a variable from the user(i.e console) it happens to be reading from the file and gives me Input Mismatch exception(as it reads string value from the file and not from the console). Below is the excerpt from my code. How can I fetch input from the console instead of the file?

```
public class PostFix{ 

    String operators[] = new String[]{"+","-","*","/","_","!","#","^","<","<=",">",">=","==","!=","&&","||","$"};
    ArrayList<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> variable_value = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PostFix pf = new PostFix();
    pf.getVariables();

}

public void getVariables(){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String tokens[] = line.split(" ");

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println("in geVariables()");
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){

            if(!Arrays.asList(operators).contains(tokens[i])){

                try{
                Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);    
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //e.printStackTrace();

                    variables.add(tokens[i]);
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value of "+tokens[i]);
                    variable_value.add(sc.nextInt());
                }

            }

        }

    }
    sc.close();     
    }   

}
```

Error:

> Please enter the value of a 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>   at PostFix.getVariables(PostFix.java:51)
>   at PostFix.main(PostFix.java:16)

Contents of in.dat file:

> 2 a + b _ * ! c c ^ 15 / # - $
>   value x + value y - != x y <= && $

Comment: Use as `Java PostFix`.

Comment: @Aashil `java PostFix < in.dat` means "run `java PostFix` and act like I typed everything in in.dat on the console". There is no way to read from the console, since console reading is redirected to in.dat. You need to *not* use `< in.dat`.

Answer (score 1):

```
java PostFix < in.dat
```

means that all the standard input will be taken from `in.dat` file.

Your Java code does not know about this redirect. It simply reads from `System.in` (i.e. standard input), which often means *keyboard*.

So, the solution is to simple let your code run without any redirecting as

```
java PostFix
```